# Where do I save a variable that should not be overwritten when I refresh the page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am pretty new to Rails and Ruby and still wrapping my head around the hole concept of Rails.

What I want to do:
I'm creating a shift-planner with a view of one week and want to create a button that will show the next/last week.

What I did:

I have 3 tables that are relevant. shift, person and test (contains types of shifts)
Where both Test and Person have one to many relations to Shift.

In my controller I did the following:

```
def index
  @todos = Todo.all
  @shifts = Shift.all
  @people = Person.all

  @start_of_week = Date.new(2015,8,7)
  @end_of_week = Date.new(2015,8,11)
```

view:

```
<% person.shifts.where(:date_of_shift =>  @start_of_week..@end_of_week).order(:date_of_shift).each do |shift| %>
    <td>
        <%="#{shift.test.name} #{shift.date_of_shift}"%>
    </td>
<%end%>
```

My Idea was I would make a link where I would increment both Dates and refresh my Page

```
<a href="/todos/new">
    Next Week
    <% @start_of_week += 7 %>
    <% @end_of_week += 7 %>
</a>
```

Unfortuately that doesn't work. Cause everytime I call the index function in my controller it sets the date on the default value.

And I'm pretty clueless how to fix this problem in a rails way.
My only would be to somehow pass the dates as parameter to the index function or something like that.

The general structure is:
I scaffolded a Todo view/controller/db just for the sake of having a view / controller and my 3 tables.

Thx for the help.
PS: I'm using the current version of ruby and rails on lubuntu15 (shouldn't be really releveant^^)

Comment: This is no different than paging, which generally sends a page number to the server. In your case something like a date and you pull the week of that date, or a date range, or whatever.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. i have to send the data through params back to the controller

Answer (score 0):

The controller method will be invoked every time someone `loads` the page. If you want to have temporarily persistent storage you should look into cookies (generally sessions are easier to use but in your case it might be relevant to let the client change the data too, click on back/forward buttons and you don't want to have a HTTP request for every little interaction, right?). You can find the relevant documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies).

Using the variable could look like this:

```
# in the controller
cookies[:start_of_week] ||= Date.new(2015,8,7)

# in the view
cookies[:start_of_week]
```

Maybe you want to work with an integer instead of a date object here if you plan on using it on the client side, but then you would have to take that into account in your views.

**Edit:** On re-reading your question I realized that my answer didn't address several things.

Why is the code you tried not working?

```
<a href="/todos/new">
  Next Week
  <% @start_of_week += 7 %>
  <% @end_of_week += 7 %>
</a>
```

When writing your views you have to be aware that it will be evaluated on the server side and then be sent to the client side (web browser in this case). You increment the instance values `@start_of_week` and `@end_of_week` when the page is rendered but not later.

So either you have the link go to a special action in your controller that will handle the new value set the  cookie/session variable (later one is an option only in this case) and render a new page and send it back to the user **or** you use Javascript and do this on the client side and change the cookie so no unescessary additonal requests have to be made (but then thinking about it you will most probably need to load data from the server anyway so it might not make any difference which one you take).

Comment: Using cookies/session for storing data as highly transient as this, it is... suboptimal, to put it mildly. One should rather send them via query string.